# FormData Returns empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use FormData to send user-entered data in a POST request with the fetch API. The problem is that when I create a new FormData object with the form that I've created, it keeps creating an empty object - no entries/keys/values

```
export class FinancialDocumentsController {
  constructor(private requestWithToken: <T>(config: AxiosRequestConfig) => Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>) {}
  
  public createFinancialDocumentsFilesUpload = ({ document, ...data }: CreateFinancialDocumentsFilesUploadReq) => {

    console.log(document, 'document');// {name: "36-2.png",size: 12251,type: "image/png"}

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('document', document);
   
    console.log('formData', formData);//{empty}

    return this.requestWithToken<CreateFinancialDocumentsFilesUploadRes>({
      method: 'POST',
      url: FINANCIAL_DOCUMENTS_FILES_UPLOAD,
      data,
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't see you sending formData in request - you have data which is not the same variable

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand. in console.log formData is empty

Comment: I see. Is "document" an object that is NOT an actual form? If so, I believe you need to set the properties yourself or call a serializer.

Comment: Here is a little example of setting the properties yourself if you're not sending an actual form [example](https://barker.codes/blog/serialize-form-data-into-an-array-in-vanilla-js/)

Comment: `path: "36-2.png"
lastModified: 1653597354951
lastModifiedDate: Thu May 26 2022 23:35:54 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) {}
name: "36-2.png"
size: 12251
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File`

Comment: this is my object and I still have not succeeded